# Configure Always Encrypted for existing column through t-sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, always-encrypted

I have a scenario where I need to encrypt few of the existing columns through "Always Encrypted", but I am in need to do through t-Sql scripts(The tested script needs to be executed in production environment). How could this be done?

Similar to below

```
ALTER TABLE testTable ALTER COLUMN StringColumn  NVARCHAR(20) COLLATE
Latin1_General_BIN2  ENCRYPTED WITH (
ENCRYPTION_TYPE = DETERMINISTIC,
ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256',
COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = CEK_Auto4)
```

But,The above code throws the following error

> Operand type clash: nvarchar is incompatible with nvarchar(20)
>   encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC',
>   encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256',
>   column_encryption_key_name = 'CEKName',
>   column_encryption_key_database_name = 'DBName')

Note: I don't have provisions to execute PowerShell scripts. I already have t-SQL script for generating keys

Comment: A way to generate the raw SQL is to use the wizard for your operation and use the 'Script to new window' function that is available usually at the top right of the window in a options(?) button.

Comment: This *should* be possible once you move up to 2019 with the [Secure Enclaves](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-enclaves?view=sqlallproducts-allversions) feature. One of their first *examples* of the use for this feature is "You can issue in-place encryption using the ALTER TABLE Transact-SQL statement"

Comment: what is the SSMS version you are using ?

Comment: I only have 2017 version...

Comment: @dfundako does this feature exist in sql server 2017..?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thx...but for the near future 2019 is not an option for me

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that, because SQL Server can't decrypt and encrypt your data. This can happens only on client side (application, SSMS, PowerShell). Essentially, you must add new encrypted columns and copy the unencrypted data from the existing one. Please note, that this can't be done by executing simple "update table set encrypted_column = unencrypted_column" T-SQL statement, because SQL Server can't encrypt/decrypt the data. So either you must do this in the application level, or run the SSMS wizard and save the process as PowerShell script, which you can run against your production server later.